# Datefield compare and validate in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for a way to validate two input datefields in my form.

I have a start date and end date 
and conditions to check are

1.start date should not be greater than end date
2.end date should not be less than start date.

I'm trying to create a directive, if there is already a solution, can you please share.

Comment: Yes, please look at `ui-validate` http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/